# How can I keep my app running in the background?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, background-process

I am creating an application in which I need to always be connected via a TCP socket. My application already works well in terms of the connection, but when it gets sent to the background, the android system eventually kills the process. This causes it to become disconnected from the server.

I've been looking for a way to always keep the application alive, but haven't found anything.
Could someone tell me what would be the best way to make it so that my application is not closed when it's in the background, or, barring this, make it restart itself if it is closed?
I'm starting with this and is producing me a headache :S

EDIT
This is part of my code:

```
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

      Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() {
                Playit();               }
        }).start();


     return START_STICKY;
  }
```

The app appears to be frozen on startup, though. I do not have a lot of experience, so maybe my mistake is simple and I haven't noticed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Service and start it via `startService()`. It will run until Android stops it for resources

Some documentation on services:

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Sorry for delay, i was reading about services and I tried to create one but if I close the app the service stops, I want when I close my app, the service continues to run and when you reopen the app check if the service is still working, if not, restart it.
Maybe my questions are dumb, but I'm a rookie and still do not understand so much u.u

Comment: If you start the Service via 'startService' then the Service won't stop when you stop your Activity.

Comment: so if the app is closed, to reopen it as I can check if the service is running? and if you just start with StartService (intent) I can communicate with an object of the service?

Comment: You can communicate: after startService, call bindService and then communicate via that. Or send Intents via multiple startService calls.

Comment: thanks,I use the bindservice like you said and it worked fine .. and when I close my app, called unbindservice to not close the service and it works well. but over time, approximately 30 min service stops working, but still remains in the list of running services .. What will be happening?

Comment: Could be that Android just kills your Service for resource. If you start it with START_STICKY it will be automatically restarted after it has been killed.

Comment: I edited my question to add some code where I call the START_STICKY. But I'm not sure if this well applied the method ..

Answer (score 0):

User a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). Services are used to perform long-running operations in the background, like sending/receiving data in a connection with a server.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Android's [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class. Note though, that a `Service` is NOT a separate thread, it is just a part of your application thread, it is just handled differently by the OS in terms of creating and destroying.

If you need an extra thread, you can of course create one in a `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, the straight answer to you question is to host a thread that keeps the connection alive into a service.

However I want to remember you that you are in a resource limited environment, where having a persistent connection in background (with the overhead of the tcp protocol) may result into battery drain and angry users.

You should ask yourself if you really want to keep the connection persistent forever, or for a limited amount of time, or just after some events that might be triggered by a gcm message or if you could just go for polling, maybe using an [inexact alarm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) .

Another option would be to establish the connection only when you application is in foreground. Anyway, it certainly depends on what you want to do with your application.

Comment: you let me explain a little, my app needs to be connected for securitybecause the purpose is to "monitor" our vendors. know where they are when I needed. Know when they go out of their path. so I need that is always connected to our server.If ever disconnected, could not get his position, or some data to compile my app

Answer (score -1):

The nature of OS is as such, that is it is supposed to kill background processes because of limited memory resources i guess . Maybe you should check out ***Watchdog*** its some kind of background process manager . I am not that used to the android system but this is what i could find from my research .
Hope that helps :)

Maybe this will help you  :

http://lifehacker.com/5608163/watchdog-monitors-your-android-for-run+away-processes